# Как правильно писать if else?

Tags: c++, if, синтаксис, условия

Вопрос про стандарты `if` и `else`

Бывает что в коде можно писать `else` а можно не писать, например

```
    if (Условие) {
     // код 1
    }
    else {
     // код 2
    }
```

и вариант 2

```
    if (Условие) {
     // код 1
    }
     // код 2
```

Вопрос такой, как будет более правильно, писать `else` или нет?

Comment: Что значит "как правильно"? Это же соверешенно разные коды.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (Условие) {
 // код 1
}
else {
 // код 2
}
```

Если *Условие* истинно, выполнится *код 1*, если ложно - *код 2*.

```
if (Условие) {
 // код 1
}
// код 2
```

Если *Условие* истинно, выполнится *код 1*, *код 2* выполнится независимо от того, ложно или истинно *Условие*.

Разница понятна? И *правильно писать* так, как требует ваша задача. Бессмысленно спрашивать, что правильно покупать в магазине - молоко или хлеб...

Вопрос имеет смысл только в том случае, если из кода 1 выхода нет - происходит какой-то переход с помощью исключения, `return` или иной. Тогда в принципе дело вкуса, как писать. Но лично я предпочел бы второй вариант - потому что *Код 2* в этом случае **никак не связан с условием**, а писать его в ветви `if-else` - воспринимается как то, что он как-то связан с условием.

Comment: Это я понял, но бывает что понятия одинаковые, например if вызывает брейк или что то иное что выкидывает из условия. И тут встает вопрос если значения не имеет и при неверном условии выполниться код 2, надо ли писать else.

Comment: Тут если посмотреть более глубокий вопрос, как видит программист когда читает код, что он думает если видит в коде else и что думает если else нету.

Comment: Ваш вопрос имеет смысл только в том случае, если из *кода  1* выхода нет. Тогда - дело вкуса; лично я предпочел бы второй вариант - потому что *Код 2* НИКАК не связан с условием.

Comment: понял значит else не желателен если не нужен.

Comment: @zip: Если вопрос об этом, то почему это не указано в вопросе?

Comment: @And Вы внимательно читали ответ?...

Comment: @And Внимательность в том, чтобы понять, что это - выполнение кода 2 в любом случае -- относится к *общему случаю*. И только затем в ответе сказано, что может существовать *частный случай*, который совершенно не отменяет общий...

Comment: @And последняя правка в ответ была внесена вместе с моим первым комментарием. Вше замечание более позднее; в вопросе же я добавлял только метки.